# Error while writing a web service in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I wrote a simple webservice in php on my linux machine. Here is the code:
`service.php`

```
<?php
    require 'lib/nusoap.php';
    include 'functions.php';
    $server=new nusoap_server();
    $server->configureWSDL("demo"."urn:demo");
    $server->register(
        "price", //name of the function
        array("name"=>'xsd:string'), //inputs
        array("return"=>'xsd:inter')  //outputs
    );
    HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

`functions.php`

```
<?php

function price($name){
    $details=>array(
        'abc'=>123,
        'qwe'=>34   
    );
    foreach ($details as $n => $p) {
        if ($name==$n) {
            $price=$p;
        }
    }
    return $price;
}

/*function countname(){

}*/

?>
```

But I got error like this:

> [Wed Jul 15 00:10:54.675740 2015] [:error] [pid 1564] [client 127.0.0.1:40356] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/html/phpWebService/service.php on line 11

I'm unable to understand this error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
```

To PHP it looks like you're trying to assign to a constant. Either add a `$` to make a variable, or use `define()` to create a constant with that value.

Comment: I changed my code like this: `define("HTTP","HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA");
 constant("HTTP") = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';` and I got this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in /var/www/html/phpWebService/service.php on line 12`

Comment: You are defining a constant `HTTP` with the string value of "HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA". The `constant()` function is for getting the values of constants programmatically, not setting them. I think you mean to do this: `define('HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA', isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');`

Comment: yeah, right. I corrected my mistake, ran it and got another error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /var/www/html/phpWebService/functions.php on line 4`

Answer (score 2):

```
HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---constant
```

you cannot assign a value to a constant, you can only `define()` them.

Answer (score -2):

check for any missing semi colon or closing bracket.
usually it will refer an error in a line number just after u missed some thing on.